# SQL select based on multiple rows values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Here is an image attached for a mini-blog I am designing for a small site. I would like to make a SQL Select statement where I get blog id for blogs where its `status = '1'` and its `categories LIKE '%blog%'`. How do I make a single SQL call where I get all active blogs that has "blog" in its category?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something? It looks like a rather simple query.

Comment: I have tried to get select all the blogs that is currently active and then afterwords I make a select statement e.g. `WHERE blog_id = :id AND field = 'categories' AND data LIKE '%blog%'`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select b.blog_id
from blogs b
where (b.field = 'status' and b.data = '1') or
      (b.field = 'categories' and b.data LIKE '%blog%')
group by b.blog_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that "status" and "categories" only appear once.  Otherwise, you need:

```
having count(distinct field) = 2
```

Comment: This is great thanks.. If I need to count the amount of blogs where these credentials is given - can I just change `select b.blog_id from` to `select count(*) from` ?

Comment: @Dimser . . . No.  You would need to include this as a subquery to count the rows.